# How to add custom cell formatting to display year (ex: 2017) as FY17

Tags: excel

Basically title.

How do you extract last two digits and display that in custom cell formatting?

Edit1: Added screenshot for further clarification

I want the cells content to be EXACTLY 2017 (I'm using sumif function to extract data from another database). However, I want its display to be FY17, via custom cell formatting.

Is it possible to do this in excel?

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tmln.png)

Edit2: Figured it's impossible to do it. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Use `="FY"&TEXT(TODAY(),"YY")`

Comment: Or in custom number format `"FY"yy`

Comment: Or even `F\Yyy`

Comment: Hello Harun. I want the content of the cell to be 2017 and want to use format cells to display it as FY17. I believe you are using functions which will not work in custom cell formatting.

Comment: FYI, `2017` on it's own is not a valid date in Excel, or rather: it is a valid date but not one in the year 2017.

Comment: @Jvdv Oh. I want the cell's content to be exactly 2017 without any day/month. This is because I'm using it as a condition for a SUMIFS function from another database (attached image in post).

Comment: @JvdV so there's no work around? because when I use your's and Harun's recommendation, I need to enter the day and month.

Comment: Yes, 2017 is an integer that, when used as a representation of a date, equals 9th of july 1905. I don't know a workaround unless you use maybe VBA?

Comment: Got it. Appreciate your help JvdV!

Comment: You *could* do it with a custom format of `00"FY"00` if you press Ctrl+j after the second zero in the format code, format the cell with wrap text on, and make the row height fractionally larger than normal.

Comment: Damn haha yeah that's one way to do it.